# rosmake dont know std?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I got an issue compiling my node with rosmake.
it didn't find std :

```
 error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

Did I miss something ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228806/rosmake-dont-know-std-?/) by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2016-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`to_string()` is a `C++11` feature (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/)). Thus, you need to configure the `CMakeLists.txt` accordingly.

Also, you should consider switching to `catkin` ;-)

For `catkin` and with `CMake >= 2.8.12` and a suitable g++ version (from Ubuntu 14.04 onward? I'm not quite sure) best use:

```
target_compile_options(<TARGET> PRIVATE -std=c++11)
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-03-11**:
I know catkin rooks but it's too complicate for the basic node I developped.
Here is what I put in my makefile :

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    add_definitions(-std=gnu++0x)
endif()
```